# simple groovy replaceall regex in a list

Tags: regex, groovy

I am trying to remove the extra space and (2) in my current list and print the new list. 
But getting an error for the below code.

```
def my_list = ["abc (2)","def edf","qwe erfw" ]
def my_new_list = my_list.replaceAll(~/ \([0-9]\)$/, "")
print "my_new_list : ${my_new_list}"
```

Expected Output

```
my_new_list : [abc,def edf,qwe erfw]
```

Error:

```
Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.replaceAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.regex.Pattern, String) values: [ \([0-9]\)$, ]
Possible solutions: replaceAll(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.util.ArrayList.replaceAll() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.regex.Pattern, String) values: [ \([0-9]\)$, ]
Possible solutions: replaceAll(java.util.function.UnaryOperator)
```

Comment: and the error is what? Did you email it to me or send it through the postal service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to call replace on each element in the list. You can use `collect`, or the `*.` operator like so

```
my_list*.replaceAll(~/ \([0-9]\)$/, "")
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me.